# Rails Completed 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I don't know what the heck is going on here, I just updated my rails from 3.1.0rc4 to 3.1.0 and I suddenly find that all ajax won't work, It's causing 406 error all the time. Everything was perfectly fine before I update to 3.1.0

Guys, I am going to lose controll now, help me.

Comment: Could it be the jquery-rails gem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Make sure that you're setting the correct content-type and that your controllers respond to the specified format. This often happens if the request content-type is set to 'application/json' and your controller doesn't have either respond_to :json declared or a format.json response in your action.