# rails turbo_stream is not working on a rails 7 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7, turbo-rails, hotwire

I am trying to submit a form and return a turbo_stream on a rails 7.0 application.
In my form I have the following.

```
 <%= form_with url: "/request_trial", method: :post, format: :turbo_stream do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :name, I18n.t('marketing.form.name'), class: 'form-label required' %>
  <%= form.text_field :name, class:"form-control", required: true %>

  <%= form.submit I18n.t('marketing.form.send'), class: 'btn btn-trial'  %>
<% end %>
```

In my controller I have the following

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.turbo_stream do |format|
    render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.replace(:'marketing-request-trial-form',
                                              partial: 'marketing/request_trial')
  end
end
```

This gives me an error `ActionController::UnknownFormat`

Although I have a format specify in my form, it seems that format is `html` when I submit the form.

I can see where this is coming from, on my request headers I have the following

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
```

I need to add on the request header the `text/vnd.turbo-stream.html` type, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

- you need emphasis the format type

```
format.turbo_stream do
   render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.replace(@article, partial: 'welcome/form')
end
```

- you can reference [Rails Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 64ms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13851494/15073910)
- welcome_controller.rb

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @article = Article.first
  end

  def update_article
    @article = Article.find(article_params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.update(article_params)
        format.turbo_stream do
          render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.replace(@article, partial: 'welcome/form')
        end
      end

    end
  end

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:id,:title, :body)
  end
end
```

- index.html.erb

```
<h1>Welcome ! This is a tutorial about Rails forms</h1>
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(@article) do %>
  <%= form_with  model: @article, url: update_article_path, method: :post, format: :turbo_stream do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_field :id %>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :body %>
    <%= form.submit "Update" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

- _form.html.erb

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(@article) do %>
  <h1>New Book</h1>
  <div class="card card-body">
    <label>title</label>
    <input value="<%= @article.title %>">
  </div>
<% end %>
```

- schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2022_02_16_084944) do
  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got `ActionController::UnknownFormat` exception is that you only respond turbo_stream format, but the actual format is HTML(You didn't pass the correct format).

#### Solution 1

`format: :turbo_stream` is assumed to be passed as an argument of URL helpers rather than form helpers. For example:

```rb
some_url_helper_path(format: :turbo_stream)
```

In your literal URL case should be:

```
<%= form_with url: "/request_trial.turbo_stream", method: :post do |form| %>
```

#### Solution 2

Solution 1 can make controller respond turbo_stream correctly. But due to the [bug](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/issues/491#issuecomment-988470263), you might see turbo_stream as plain text instead of replacing views. Before a new version of Turbo js release, you can add a hidden field to forms manually:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="format" value="turbo_stream">
```